# What are the uses of a spare Wireless Router?

Tags: wireless-router

I have a Asus RT-N12 LX Wireless N Router lying around as my ISP has decided that only their routers are good enough. Apart from selling my spare router, what else can I use it for?

Comment: Do you want me to delete the question? Would be happy to do so.

Comment: You don't necessarily have to delete it. A good place to ask for this would be [chat] if you want.

Comment: Install custom firmware is a possibility (tomato, openwrt, dd-wrt), extend your wireless coverage, or make it as a wireless client, and share the internet via the wired connection (For use of devices that don't use wireless), a fair bit of possibility. Depends on what you want to do. The question may be edited to narrow down what you MIGHT want to do, and we can probably tell you whether yes it is possible or not.

Answer (score 1):

Put [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Asus_RT-N12) on it and use it to extend your network as a bridge repeater, a dedicated AP for a VPN connection, and etc. Depends on your needs/want, but you can do a lot of things with a spare router.

Comment: Yes I wanted to know some of the interesting ways that people have come up with to use a spare router. A list would be interesting.